# jQuery Sanity Check

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is driving me crazy. Please someone tell me I'm not crazy:

```
var constraints = $('.traffic-constraints :input');
console.log(constraints);

var i;
for (i = 0; i < constraints.length; i++) {
  if (constraints[i].val() > 0) { //<-------- errorrzz
....
```

the console tells me that i do, in fact, have input objects in my selector (5 of them). however, i get the following error: `constraints[i].val is not a function`

wtf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) it's easier :)

But, to answer the question **why** doesn't it work...you're dealing with a dom element with that index, you need to wrap it or `.eq(i)` acesss it:

```
for (i = 0; i < constraints.length; i++) {
  if ($(constraints[i]).val() > 0) {
```

Or (better, but still use `.each()`!):

```
for (i = 0; i < constraints.length; i++) {
  if (constraints.eq(i).val() > 0) {
```

Comment: thanks... i figured this out the second before you posted this!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has an [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method to loop through the elements of a collection. You can use it as such:

```
$('.traffic-constraints :input').each(function(index) {
    if($(this).val() > 0) {
       doSomething();
    }
});
```

The reason why your loop isn't working is that the elements are not extended with jQuery's methods. The following fixes it:

```
var constraints = $('.traffic-constraints :input');
console.log(constraints);

var i;
for (i = 0; i < constraints.length; i++) {
    if ($(constraints[i]).val() > 0) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

But for reasons of code maintainability and best practices, use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/). It isn't noticeably slower and is easier to maintain and understand.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing elements like that (e.g. `$('.traffic-constraints :input')[0]`) returns the *HTML* element (or DOM node, to be more pedantic). If you want to get the element jQuery-wrapped, call `constraints.eq (i)`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)?

Comment: i could, but it's a bit slower... what is wrong with what i'm doing?

Comment: If it works though, I wouldn't be too upset at it being slower.

Comment: i would still like to know for learning's sake what i'm doing wrong here